# Run PHP Code After Form Submission And Redirect

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to run some php code after a form is submitted on my website. It redirects to another page to email the information, then uses header() to return to the previous page. What I would like to happen is to load a small message that shows that the message was sent successfully, but I'm not sure how to do this after being redirected from another page. I'm hoping to use php or jquery to accomplish this, and I'm including the code I'm using below. I have tried to use the session_start function to do this, but the echoed text remains on the page after the user leaves.

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
<tr>
<td class="label">Name:</td>
<td class="input"><input type="text" maxlength="40" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Please enter your name." required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Email:</td>
<td class="input"><input type="email" maxlength="24" name="email" title="Please enter an email address." required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Subject:</td>
<td class="input"><input type="text" maxlength="24" name="subject" title="Please enter a subject." required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Message:</td>
<td class="input"><textarea rows="9" maxlength="1000" name="message" title="Please enter a message." required></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</form>

<?php
$to = "kouen922@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message From Your Website: ".trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["subject"]));
$message = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]));
$headers = "Reply To: ".trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]))."" ."\r\n". "From: " .trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]))."";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header("Location: index.php#contact");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

```
header("Location: index.php?thankyou#contact");
```

Then do a conditional for `isset($_GET['thankyou'])` and print out a message.

Comment: Perfect, this helped a lot.

Comment: @JordanU. very glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using php, use Jquery(since you mentioned about it) and use its potential to send your form data, using ajax post request. In that way you can stay on same page without ever navigating to another page(because you are returning back), and also you can display the message once the post request is complete, ajax POST method returns a callback once the request is complete
[Read about it here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description: form page -- php email page -- back to form page, then just add the php email part into form page:

index.php:

```
<?php
$data = init_data();
if ($data['cmd']) {
    $err = main_send($data);
}
if (!$data['cmd'] || $err) {
    main_form($data, $err);
}

function init_data() {
    $arr = ['cmd', 'name', 'email', 'subject', 'message'];
    foreach ($arr as $k) {
        $data[$k] = isset($_POST[$k]) ? trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST[$k])) : '';
    }
    return $data;
}

function main_send($data) {
    if (!$data['name']) {
        return 'What is your name?';
    } elseif (!$data['email']) {
        return 'What is your email?';
    } elseif (!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return 'Your email is not valid';
    } elseif (!$data['message']) {
        return 'Please say something';
    }

    $to = 'kouen922@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Message From Your Website: ' . $data['subject'];
    $message = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]));
    $headers = 'Reply To: ' . $data['email'])) . "\r\nFrom: " . $data['name']));
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo '<p>Thank you very much for the feedback</p>';
}

function main_form($data, $err = '') {
    if ($err) {
        echo '<p class="err">' , $err , '</p>';
    }
    echo 'your original form html here ...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

form code

```
<div id="message"></div>
<form method="post" id="email-form" action="">
<tr>
<td class="label">Name:</td>
<td class="input"><input type="text" maxlength="40" id="name" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" title="Please enter your name." required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Email:</td>
<td class="input"><input type="email" maxlength="24" id="email" name="email" title="Please enter an email address." required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Subject:</td>
<td class="input"><input type="text" maxlength="24" id="subject" name="subject" title="Please enter a subject." required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Message:</td>
<td class="input"><textarea rows="9" id="message" maxlength="1000" name="message" title="Please enter a message." required></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
```

email.php code

```
<?php

//email.php

$to = "kouen922@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message From Your Website: ".trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["subject"]));
$message = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]));
$headers = "Reply To: ".trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]))."" ."\r\n". "From: " .trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]))."";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo 'Mail was successfully send';

?>
```

Jquery code :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#email-form").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var email= $('#email').val();
       var name= $('#name').val();
       var subject= $('#subject').val();
       var messege = $('#messege').val();
       $.ajax({
           url: "email.php",
           type:"POST",
           data: 'email='+email + '&name='+name +'&subject='+subject+'&message='+message,
           success: function(data){
           $('#message').html(data);    
            setTimeout(function(){ //redirect after 5 sec 
            window.history.go(-1); // Simulates a back button click
           },5000); // time in milli sec
           }

           });
        });
   });

</script>
```